# Does anyone is able to explain why when console logging the variable countOnlineUsers it does not hold the count in memory?

Tags: javascript, object, iteration

I am trying to iterate through a bi-dimensionsal object in order to count how many users have their online property set to online, however when I do try to console.log() the countOnlineUsers variable this does not hold the count and it seems to being reset each time the loop hit a "new" online property of "new" user

```js
    let users = {
      Alan: {
        age: 27,
        online: false
      },
      Jeff: {
        age: 32,
        online: true
      },
      Sarah: {
        age: 48,
        online: false
      },
      Ryan: {
        age: 19,
        online: true
      },
      George: {
        age: 32,
        online: true
      }
    };
    
    function countOnline(obj) {
    
      for(let user in users) {

    if (!users.hasOwnProperty(user)) continue; //Makes first check

      let obj = users[user];     
      for(let prop in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue; //Makes second check

          let countOnlineUsers = 0;
          if(obj[prop] === true) {            
            countOnlineUsers++;
          }
          console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
          console.log(countOnlineUsers);        
      }        
  

    }

    }
    
    console.log(countOnline(users));
```

Comment: Your function does not return anything.

Comment: Question is very unclear but probably related to declaring new instance of `countOnlineUsers`  every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the value to `0` on every iteration of the loop:

```
for(let user in users) {
    //...
    let countOnlineUsers = 0;
    //...
}
```

Since you only modify the value once within that iteration, it can only ever be `0` or `1`.  Instead, set the value *before* the loop:

```
let countOnlineUsers = 0;
for(let user in users) {
    //...
}
```

Then each iteration of the loop will be modifying the same value (if its condition is met) instead of always creating a new value.

(Note that you have nested loops, I mostly had to guess which one you wanted to increment the value for.)

Your original code with this modification:

```js
let users = {
      Alan: {
        age: 27,
        online: false
      },
      Jeff: {
        age: 32,
        online: true
      },
      Sarah: {
        age: 48,
        online: false
      },
      Ryan: {
        age: 19,
        online: true
      },
      George: {
        age: 32,
        online: true
      }
    };
    
    function countOnline(obj) {
    
      let countOnlineUsers = 0;
      for(let user in users) {

    if (!users.hasOwnProperty(user)) continue; //Makes first check

      let obj = users[user];     
      for(let prop in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue; //Makes second check

          if(obj[prop] === true) {            
            countOnlineUsers++;
          }
          console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
          console.log(countOnlineUsers);        
      }        
  

    }

    }
    
    console.log(countOnline(users));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help David, I do apologize for my question not being clear I was so frustrated as I have spent the whole morning try to wrap my head around this issue. I am more frustrated now as it seems to be a very basic knowledge problem...

Answer (score 0):

This is becuase `countOnhlineUsers` is inside the `loop`. You need to declare it outside it. And change it inside

```js
let users = {
      Alan: {
        age: 27,
        online: false
      },
      Jeff: {
        age: 32,
        online: true
      },
      Sarah: {
        age: 48,
        online: false
      },
      Ryan: {
        age: 19,
        online: true
      },
      George: {
        age: 32,
        online: true
      }
    };
    
    function countOnline(obj) {
      let countOnlineUsers = 0;
      for(let user in users) {

    if (!users.hasOwnProperty(user)) continue; //Makes first check

      let obj = users[user];     
      
      for(let prop in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue; //Makes second check

          
          if(obj[prop] === true) {            
            countOnlineUsers++;
          }
          console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
          console.log(countOnlineUsers);        
      }        
  

    }

    }
    
    console.log(countOnline(users));
```